# receiving a bunch of (incomplete)s during a GREP and AWK command

Tags: macos, grep, bash-scripting, awk, arp

when I use this command:

```
arp -a | grep "192.168.0.19" | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

I receive these results... the ff:ff mac address is what I want, but why do I get a field of (incomplete)s? All I want is just the MAC address from the specific IP of which I'm grepping from.

```
ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
(incomplete)
(incomplete)
(incomplete)
(incomplete)
(incomplete)
(incomplete)
(incomplete)
(incomplete)
(incomplete)
(incomplete)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you have recently tried to access `192.168.0.190`, `192.168.0.191`,…  `192.168.0.199` (notice there are 10 `(incomplete)`s). These addresses couldn't be reached, still kernel cache keeps their incomplete entries for a while.

I guess if you did `arp -a | grep "192.168.0.19"` you could discover this by yourself.

My `arp -a` (on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS) puts IP addresses in parentheses. Try:

```
arp -a | grep "(192.168.0.19)" | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

Or you can filter out the `(incomplete)`s with `-v` option of `grep`:

```
arp -a | grep "192.168.0.19" | grep -v "(incomplete)" | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

Oops! The latter version may return MAC addresses of hosts you do not expect. Think what will happen if `192.168.0.19` has incomplete entry and e.g. `192.168.0.190` has complete one. I leave it here for educational purpose.

Yet `grep -v` may be useful (notice the parentheses next to IP address are back):

```
arp -a | grep "(192.168.0.19)" | grep -v "(incomplete)" | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

This way you get desired MAC address, or nothing if there is no complete entry for this IP.

**Finally my `arp` can return info about specific IP only:** `arp -a 192.168.0.19`. This is the best way to start. The whole command may look like this:

```
arp -a 192.168.0.19 | grep -v "(incomplete)" | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

Oops again! Pitfalls everywhere. This last command will return no output if the hostname of `192.168.0.19` is like `foobar-(incomplete)`. Improved version:

```
arp -a 192.168.0.19 | awk '{ print $4 }' | grep -v "(incomplete)"
```

Comment: yeah, you might be right, it has to do with me using nmap. It seems when I use that command to ping an IP address, then the "incomplete's" show themselves. Is there a way to avoid that when using nmap?

Comment: @JamesDean "Is there a way to avoid that when using nmap?" – I think there's no easy way, but there's no need either. My approach with argument to `arp` or with parentheses should solve your problem.